# Facebook login not redirecting

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

Why is the following not working?

```
// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {

    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

} else {

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$login_url);

}
```

Using xdebug, I can see that it is going through the `else` section, but when it gets to the end of the file, it stays on the current page, instead of opening the new `login_url` page which should show the facebook login screen.

Anyone know why it's not going to the facebook page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.  I had a typo...  I was assigning the url to `$logoutUrl` and was trying to get the url from `$logout_url`...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution in php:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => $scope,
            'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
            ));


            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '', // app id
  'secret' => '', // the secret
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  header("Location: ".$login_url); // the user is not logged in, redirect him to the login page
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the only difference I see is the `exit()`?  I have already tried this and it made no difference.